# Printing Datatable with Many Columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am trying to print a jquery datatable with many columns. The whole table is shown on the screen but when I click print, the columns keep getting stretched. As a result some columns get clipped from the printed document. I have tried using the customize function to set the td width but to no effect. Can anyone help me out?

This is what I tried following datatables documentation:

```
customize: function ( win ) {
$(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('display').css('font-size', '5px');
$(win.document.body).find('table').css('table-layout','auto');
$(win.document.body).find('th').css('width','10%');
$(win.document.body).find('td').css('width','10%');
}
```

This is what I see on screen (before print):
https://screenshots.firefox.com/VNmLTF2b6UXlar7l/localhost

And this is what I get when I click on print (see the columns have stretched quite a lot):
[table after print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PGrT.png)

Comment: Have you tried to add some styles to your stylesheet with mediaquery? @media print... this are the styles for printing -> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example.